# Adding elements to ArrayList in java

Tags: java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayTest {

    private static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();


    public static void printList () {
        System.out.println("Printing the list");
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
            if (list.get(i) != null)
                System.out.println(i + " => " + list.get(i));
        }   
    }

    public static void add(Integer index, String val) {
        while(list.size() <= index)
            list.add(null);
        list.add(index, val);   
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayTest.add(8, "cover");
        ArrayTest.printList();
        ArrayTest.add(6, "and");
        ArrayTest.printList();
    }   

}
```

produces the following output

```
Printing the list
8 => cover
Printing the list
6 => and
9 => cover
```

The `add(Integer index, String val)` function adds an appropriate number of nulls to the list as a check to avoid any `IndexOutOfBoundsException` exceptions.
Can someone explain why does adding "and" to the list push "cover" a position further in the list ?

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), the ArrayList.add(int,element) *inserts* an element at the specific index, shifting subsequent elements back. The ArrayList.set(int, element) *sets* the element at the index without shifting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this is the [actual specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28int,%20E%29) of the `List.add(int index, E element)` method:

> Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list
>   (optional operation). **Shifts the element currently at that position
>   (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their
>   indices).**

As to "why": this is done to avoid overwriting the element on the specified position.

Answer (score 3):

Because the [add method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29) you used **inserts** an element at specified index. It doesn't replace the existing element at this position, it add a new, so add the index position from that towards the end.

If you need to replace the value, use the [set method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set%28int,%20E%29).

Answer (score 0):

In Java 9, there's an easy way with less number of lines without needing to initialize or `add` method. Use `collection factory` methods:

```
List<String> list = List.of("first", "second", "third");
```